# Setting size to an "inner" component

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm creating a custom component (with its ViewModel) that is composed of a list of some objects.

Each row is represented by another custom component (with its own ViewModel too).

I'd like to set the width of each row equal to the width of the "container" list...

But i can't! How can I do that?

Comment: try using Grid. and ColumnDefination set to Width="*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using a `ListBox`? If so, you need to set the `ItemContainerStyle` to stretch across the entire available width:

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignmen" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
```

Referencing this style as follows:

```
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
     </ListBox>
```

See [this forum thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/117276.aspx/1) for more details.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I had already tried the HorizontalAlignment and it did not work. Now it is perfect!!

Comment: @Francesco, if you find the answer useful, you can vote it up in addition to accepting it.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot about that @Francesco!  Apologies, it's been a while since I started.

Comment: @Francesco I upvoted your question - you now have 15 reputation ;-)